# Is it possible to get a UIButton to change a segue identifier for another button?

Tags: cocoa-touch, segue

I have a button (Say button "A") that links to another view controller via a modal segue and that segue has an identifier to pass information on using the method:

```
prepareForSegue
```

Now I want to add another button (Say button "B") to my first view controller that when pressed will simply change the segue identifier for my previous button (button "A"). So that I can still use prepareForSegue but have different data passed on.

Is this possible??

Comment: instead of having segue directly from button, have segues from view controller and when the button is pressed use perform Segue with Identifier to handle accordingly

Comment: Hi, thanks this is helpful - but how do you create a segue from view controller to view controller, does it have to be programatically? Also, I am having trouble finding information on the method "perform Segue with Identifier" for objective c!

Comment: I connected the two VC but this code won't work?  
- (IBAction)PressedOne:(id)sender {
    
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"one" sender: self];

}
- (IBAction)PressedTwo:(id)sender {
    
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"two" sender: self];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"one"]){
        SecondViewController *controller = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.isoneEnabledFr = YES;
        return;
    }

Answer (score 1):

1. Have a variable declared in your ViewController as segueId of type String assign the default segue id to it.
2. When "buttonA" is pressed, issue performSegueWithIdentifier.
3. Now ad your another button "buttonB" to your view controller and in its action, change the value of the segueId variable.
4. By this way you can invoke multiple segues from same button.
5. Also, if you wanted to send different data to different VC, then check for the segueID in your prepareForSegue method and send accordingly

note: All the segues should go from VC and not from button.

Hope it helps.